# Google Cloud Platform: Is there a way to ignore Pub/Sub messages if a Cloud Function is already processing?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am very new to Google Cloud Platform, and I am currently making some Cloud Functions in Go. I am wondering if it is possible to for a Cloud Function that is a subscriber to a topic to ignore a message if it is already processing one?

Essentially, my system sends a "done" message at some point, which spins up a Cloud function, I want to make it so that if that topic receives another done message, it doesn't start another subscriber function instance, but ignores the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it's possible to do that natively with a `Cloud Function`.

You can think having a `state` to handle this kind of use cases.

For example there is [memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-overview) with `Redis` in `Google Cloud` to store your received messages.

In your `Cloud Function`, you can use a `Python` `Redis` client to access to cache.
You can add a filter a treat only the messages that doesn't exist in the cache.

Comment: Oh right, I'll take a look at memorystore. Thanks for your answer!